# Flutter Different sized Circles in a shape that don't overlap

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter and have this question. How circles with different radius can be placed on a canvas without overlapping on one another in a circular shape? Please note that the circles are of different radius. I am using CustomPaint() and Paint() to draw these circles. Much appreciate your help

Comment: Firstly for circle, use can simply use a Container with with BoxShape.circle in decoration instead of CustomPaint. About your animation it wont be an issue to attract circles at one point from different directions. You can simply spawn them a random positions outside your screen and animate them to the center (width * 0.5,height * 0.5). But you might need to write your own custom code for collision detection and handling it.

Answer (score 0):

I took [Sarvesh Dalvi's](http://Sarvesh%20Dalvi) comment and used Container instead of Custom Paint. Later moved to Ink and Inkwell to get the ripple effect when the bubble is clicked. I used [flutter_scatter](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/flutter_scatter) to display circles in a circle/arc form and SlideTransition to give the floating effect to the bubbles. Below is the code that I came up with.

// Code for Circle

```
child: Ink(
      width: widget.bubbleData.radius,
      height: widget.bubbleData.radius,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage(widget.bubbleData.image),
            fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
          ),
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.transparent),
          gradient: LinearGradient(colors: widget.bubbleData.colors)),
      child: InkWell(
        customBorder: CircleBorder(),
        splashColor: widget.bubbleData.splashColor,
        onTap: () {
          print("Circle Tapped");
        },
```

// Code for circles in an arc form

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Scatter(
          delegate:
              LogarithmicSpiralScatterDelegate(
                  ratio: 1, a: 1, b: 1, step: 0.01, rotation: 0.3),
              children: bubbleList),
    ));
  }
```